# Java Generate Custom Stream in Pipeline

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to consume a stream of messges and generate notifications. Let's say with `Stream<Message>` comming in, my processor processes it and then generates `Stream<Notification>` according to some calculations. It's not a simple map operation, the processor has state, it needs to remember certain number of previous messages, calculating a sliding average and recognize some other patterns in order to generate the notifications stream.

I cannot find an appropriate operation to use from the Stream intermediate operations -- `filter()`, `map()` and so on. One way is to use `forEach()`. But it's a terminal operation and I cannot generate the resulting stream and pipeline it.

I'm new to Java stream and I wonder how can I use the Java stream model to achieve the above goal.

Flow:

`Stream<Message> ---> (Notification processor) ---> Stream<Notification> ---> ...`

**Edit:**

I haven't really started the implementation yet, but I can imagine the code would be like this:

```
public class NotificationProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private Averager averager;

    @Autowired
    private TrendAnalyser trendAnalyser;

    private long prevNotificationTime;

    public void consume(Message message) {


        if (message.getRate() >  averager.getAverage() + THRESHOLD) {
            // Generate notification A here
        }

        // Adjust the moving average
        averager.put(message);

        trendAnalyser.analyze(message);
        if (trendAnalyser.isFalling()) {
            Date now  = new Date();
            // Throttle
            if (now.getTime() - prevNotificationTime > 60) {
                prevNotificationTime = now.getTime();
                // Generate notification B here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's just a traditional Java class that consumes messages. I'm still learning the Stream model so I'm not sure how I can wire the class to it.

**More Edit:**

Holger's way is pretty neat and solid, I think it's a very good design. However, I later found out that I can use a class to track the state and call its methods in `Stream.map()`

```
NotificationProcessor processor;
stream.map(s -> processor.consume(s)).filter(s -> s != null)
```

Comment: *It's not a simple map operation, the processor has state, it needs to remember certain number of previous messages...* Please showcase the sample code

Comment: a _stateful_ `map` is possible, though not recommended... show some pseudo-code, it will be easier to reason

Comment: Is the order of processing important for the outcome, i.e. the stream of notifications?

Comment: @Naman Added some sample code.

Comment: @Eugene Code added.

Comment: @Amadán The order matters. It has to be processed in the original order.

Comment: @JFreebird While you're trying to consume the `Message` or actually process it into `Notification` later is not clear from the fact that your method is `void` and you generate notification is not yet known.

Comment: So a single `Message` could cause two notifications, `A` and `B` here?

Comment: @Holger Yes, but it could be a single one as well. I can use a duplicate input stream to do the other notification.

Comment: @Naman The notification can be just a String saying a certain condition happened.  Maybe it should return a string  instead.

Comment: @JFreebird With the current abstraction and the code shared, I don't see any problem with returning `String` from `consume` method in that case and performing a `Stream.map` to transform the `Stream<Message>`.

Comment: @Naman Yes, but the issue is the processor class needs to keep states, while the functional interface that Stream.map only takes a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom operations not fitting into the functional API can be implemented via the [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Spliterator.html) interface.

To give a simple example, the following operation will concatenate a `String` element with its previous element, if non-`null`:

```
public static Stream<String> concatWithPrevious(Stream<String> source) {
    boolean parallel = source.isParallel();
    Spliterator<String> sp = source.spliterator();
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<String>(
        sp.estimateSize(),
        sp.characteristics()&~(Spliterator.DISTINCT|Spliterator.SORTED)) {

        private String previous;

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super String> action) {
            return sp.tryAdvance(s -> {
                String p = previous;
                previous = s;
                action.accept(p == null? s: s == null? p: p.concat(s));
            });
        }
    }, parallel).onClose(source::close);
}
```

The central element is the `tryAdvance` method which has to invoke the `Consumer`’s `accept` method with the next element and return `true`, if there is one, or just return `false`, if the end of the stream has been reached.

There are also characteristics and an estimated size (which will be an exact size when the `SIZED` characteristic is present), which the above example will basically take from the source stream’s spliterator. I leave it as an exercise for the reader, why the `DISTINCT` and `SORTED` characteristics are removed here when present for the source stream.

Parallel processing will be enabled via the `trySplit` method, which will be inherited from `AbstractSpliterator` here. This method will perform buffering of elements into an array, which is not very efficient, but for a spliterator having such a dependency on the previous element, it’s the best we can get.

---

When we run this example with

```
concatWithPrevious(
    IntStream.range('A', 'Z')
        .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf((char)i))
        .peek(s -> System.out.println("source stream: "+s))
)
.filter(Predicate.isEqual("EF"))
.findFirst()
.ifPresent(s -> System.out.println("result: "+s));
```

we get

```
source stream: A
source stream: B
source stream: C
source stream: D
source stream: E
source stream: F
result: EF
```

demonstrating that the laziness of the Streams still is retained.

---

Taking your example sketch of your task, I’d consider changing the code like

```
public class NotificationProcessor {
    @Autowired
    private Averager averager;

    @Autowired
    private TrendAnalyser trendAnalyser;

    private long prevNotificationTime;

    public void consume(Message message, Queue<Notification> queue) {


        if (message.getRate() >  averager.getAverage() + THRESHOLD) {
            // Generate notification A here
            queue.add(…);
        }

        // Adjust the moving average
        averager.put(message);

        trendAnalyser.analyze(message);
        if (trendAnalyser.isFalling()) {
            Date now  = new Date();
            // Throttle
            if (now.getTime() - prevNotificationTime > 60) {
                prevNotificationTime = now.getTime();
                // Generate notification B here
                queue.add(…);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And utilize it in a Stream operation like

```
public static Stream<Notification> notificationProcessor(Stream<Message> source) {
    // replace with intended factory mechanism or make it a parameter
    NotificationProcessor proc = new NotificationProcessor();

    boolean parallel = source.isParallel();
    Spliterator<Message> sp = source.spliterator();
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<Notification>(
        sp.estimateSize(),
        sp.characteristics() & Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL) {

        final Queue<Notification> queue = new ArrayDeque<>(2);

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Notification> action) {
            while(queue.isEmpty()) {
                if(!sp.tryAdvance(msg -> proc.consume(msg, queue))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            action.accept(queue.remove());
            return true;
        }
    }, parallel).onClose(source::close);
}
```

Since each source element may generate between zero and two elements, there can’t be a `SIZED` characteristic, in fact, I decided to be conservative here and only retain the `ORDERED` characteristic, which you said is relevant to your operation, and added `NONNULL` which seems to be appropriate for your code.

Since each `tryAdvance` invocation is supposed to provide exactly one element or no element only when the stream end is reached, there’s a queue of up to two elements needed¹. If the queue is empty, the source will be queried until there is at least one element or the source’s end has been reached. Then, the next element will be passed to the consumer, if there is an element in the queue.

---

¹ We could work with a queue of size one here, immediately consuming the first pending element without queuing, but it would complicate the code significantly

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I really appreciate it.  Now I'm wondering whether I can new the `NotificationProcessor` in the outer block and just use it like: `myStream.map(s -> notificationProcessor.consume(s)).filter(s-> s != null).forEach(System::println)` ? This way I can still use the standard API. I'm not sure which way is better though.

Comment: I think in my way, I cannot generate two streams simultaneously, while in your approach it can be done easily.